# Is possible to communicate html5 video players

Tags: html, html5-video

I have did in my site similar to like this ( if one player plays others should pause).

I have used `ExternalInterface` for communicate with **javascript**.

Could I able to make the same effect in `html5 video` player.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can, that's what HTML 5 is here for ;-)

HTML 5 audio and video support a great number of attributes and events that can be accessed using JavaScript.

You better have a look here: http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/2010/03/01/html-5-video-dom-attributes-and-events/

Clarify your questions if you need more detailed information.